# Please invert the email → mail synonym

Tags: support, status-completed, tags, retag-request

At the moment [email](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/email) is a synonym of [mail](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/mail). This makes [mail](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/mail) the to-go tag for both email in general, and the `mail(1)` command. I propose to use [mail-command](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/mail-command) for the `mail` command (it's useful to have a tag because a free-form search will have relevant hits drowned in the mass of posts that deal with email). It's not very discoverable, unfortunately, so it would help if there wasn't a [mail](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/mail) tag. At least, the main tag should be [email](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/email).

[image: topical picture of a pony in lieu of payment for a quick reaction]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I revoked the synonym and changed all the [mail](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/mail) instances to be [email](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/email) instead, so [mail](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/mail) should die out automatically. At some point somebody should probably go through [email](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/email) to find any that should actually be [mail-command](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/mail-command); I imagine it's not very many

Comment: Since then we're reacquired a [tag:mail] tag. I've gone and retagged a couple of questions to [tag:mail-command], the rest should be tagged [tag:email]. Please make [tag:mail] a synonym of [tag:email] — there aren't many questions about `mail`, and if people don't read the tag wiki we'll retag as often.

Comment: @Gilles Done (and merged)